# Is there a way of cleaning user input without using !important?

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I'm using wp_editor to create a front end form on my WordPress site that users can post with, without having to go to the admin section. It's working, but because they can cut and paste into it, there's potential for them to be copying inline styles across that will conflict with the overall design of the site.

To get around this, I've wrapped all posts in a `div` with the class `clean`, which strips out any potential inline style: SCSS code below:

```
.clean {
            /*Stops inline styles overwriting when people cut and paste */
            * {
                font-color: inherit !important;
                font-family: inherit !important;
                font-size: inherit !important;              
                font-weight: inherit !important;                
                line-height: inherit !important;
            }
            b, strong {
                font-weight: bold !important;
            }
            p {
                margin:0;
                padding: .5em 0 !important;
                -webkit-margin-before:0;
                -webkit-margin-after:0;             
            }
        }
```

However, I know it's generally considered bad practice to use `!important` in your css, so I'm looking for a way around it. Can this be done in css?

Comment: For inline styles, no, there is no other way, apart from actually removing the inline styles. Perhaps you can find a plug-in that removes the inline styles?

Comment: Is it difficult to strip out the inline styles before the user posts garbage CSS properties? Seems better to remove them before they become a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds potentially dangerous. You should be sanitising the submitted html before saving it to your DB.

For example, someone could insert the following post:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('asd')">click me</a>
```

This isn't dangerous, but the attacker could use this method to inject anything on to your page.

To get around your example, however, the "attacker" could also include their own `<style></style>` blocks that reference any elements on your page and change it that way.

During your sanitisation you would probably want to remove all markup or get a clever parser that removes the pieces that you don't want. I personally wouldn't give permission to the public user to insert html on to my website.

Comment: It's not a public website, it's for my firm's intranet. Also, because wp_editor is a WordPress function, it already has sanitzation built in.

Comment: Ok, I'll take your word for it, I thought you had to define your own sanitisation. It has been a while since I've used it. Are you specifying a list of elements that you allow? Would this <a/> tag be removed? I assume something like a <p/> tag would be allowed through seeing as this is where you're problem lies with inline styles?